# Unable to debug with F11 with VSCODE (toggled Fullscreen)?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

It seems that <kbd>F11</kbd> for toggle fullscreen is overwrite <kbd>F11</kbd> "Step into" keyboard shortcut while debugging. How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 61):

For MacOS:

Go to `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard` and check the box `Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys`

Go to `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts` and uncheck `Mission Control -> Show Desktop F11`.

This worked for me on

- Catalina 10.15.5
- BigSur 11.3.1

Comment: The second point appears to be under "Misson Control" settings instead of "Keyboard" now (I'm on Catalina 10.15.7). There is a "Show Desktop" dropdown on "Misson Control".

Comment: Probably good to mention this is for Mac OS users...

Comment: I'm searching for an answer for Mac OS version Ventura (13.X).

Comment: Think I found it. System Settings > Desktop & Dock > Scroll down to Mission Control > click on the button "Shortcuts..." > Change Show Desktop to something else.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to change key bindings at

1. Go to <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Preference</kbd> > <kbd>Keyboard Shortcuts</kbd> (At the right side will be displayed `keybindings.json` file in `%APPDATA%\Code\User`).
2. Add `{ "key": "f11", "command": "workbench.action.debug.stepInto", "when": "inDebugMode" }` to that file.

Comment: my vscode already has this configuration, but the default doesn't work. Adding this line solved the problem.

Comment: This seems outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Go to: System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts (tab) -> Mission Control (list on the left side) -> Show Desktop (checkbox).
There are 2 options:

1. Disable option (uncheck the box),
2. Change the key (double click on the key, and then press the new key like F12 or whatever you prefer).
   (Tested on Monterey 12.1 and VSCode)

Answer (score 2):

For Ventura, OSX 13, the location of this setting has changed.

Open System Settings `>` Desktop & Dock `>` Scroll down to Mission Control `>` click on the button "Shortcuts..." `>` Change Show Desktop from F11 to something else